# Can't receive the push notification message from my php, but the online test site push is can get the message

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I can't get push notification from my php, But I can get the notification from the [online site for testing](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info).

My iOS project step is below:

1. add the setting Capabilities change to on for "Push notifications", And Background Mode selected the "remote notifications" and "background fetch".
2. add the " UserNotifications.frameworks"
3. In the AppDelegate add the ""

4.In the Appdelegate.m  add below code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
center.delegate = self;
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
    if( !error )
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
        NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
        NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
        NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
    }
}];

[center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
    NSLog(@"push settings:%@",settings);
}];

return YES;
 }

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0){

NSString *deviceTokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@""]];
deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"device token:%@",deviceTokenString);

 }


 -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler{

     UNNotificationRequest *request = notification.request;

        UNNotificationContent *content = request.content;

        NSDictionary *userInfo = content.userInfo;

        NSNumber *badge = content.badge;

        NSString *body = content.body;

UNNotificationSound *sound = content.sound;

NSString *subtitle = content.subtitle;

NSString *title = content.title;

if([notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:[UNPushNotificationTrigger class]]) {

    NSLog(@"iOS10 get remote notify:%@",userInfo);

}else {

    NSLog(@"iOS10 get local notify:{\\\\nbody:%@，\\\\ntitle:%@,\\\\nsubtitle:%@,\\\\nbadge：%@，\\\\nsound：%@，\\\\nuserInfo：%@\\\\n}",body,title,subtitle,badge,sound,userInfo);
}


completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge|
                  UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound|
                  UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
 }

    // notify click event
 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{

UNNotificationRequest *request = response.notification.request;

UNNotificationContent *content = request.content;

NSDictionary *userInfo = content.userInfo;

NSNumber *badge = content.badge;

NSString *body = content.body;

UNNotificationSound *sound = content.sound;

NSString *subtitle = content.subtitle;

NSString *title = content.title;

if([response.notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:[UNPushNotificationTrigger class]]) {
    NSLog(@"iOS10 remote notify:%@",userInfo);


}else {
            NSLog(@"local notify:{\\\\nbody:%@，\\\\ntitle:%@,\\\\nsubtitle:%@,\\\\nbadge：%@，\\\\nsound：%@，\\\\nuserInfo：%@\\\\n}",body,title,subtitle,badge,sound,userInfo);
}


completionHandler();
 }
```

5. I can get the below log:

> push settings UNNotificationSettings 0x170089510： 
>   authorizationStatus, Authorized, notificationCenterSetting, Enabled, 
>   soundSetting, Enabled, badgeSetting：Enabled, lockScreenSetting： 
>   Enabled, alertSetting： NotSupported, carPlaySetting： Enabled, 
>   alertStyle , Alert
>
> Push registration success.
>
> device token：my device token ID

6. I set the PHP code like below:

> ```
> <?php
>
>
>  $deviceToken = $row['my device token ID'];
> // Put your private key's passphrase 
> $passphrase = 'my password';
> $message = 'My first push notification!';
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> $ctx = stream_context_create();
> stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
> stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
> stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
> // Open a connection to the APNS server
> $fp = stream_socket_client(
>  'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
>  $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
> // $fp = stream_socket_client(
> //  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
> //  $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
> if (!$fp)
>  exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
> echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
> // Create the payload body
> $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,'sound' => 'default');
> // Encode the payload as JSON
> $payload = json_encode($body);
> // Build the binary notification
> $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
> // Send it to the server
> $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
> if (!$result)
>  echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
> else
>  echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
> // Close the connection to the server
> fclose($fp);
> ?>
> ```

7. then I run the php in my mac, I run the localhost/push.php , I can get the message from the web:

   **Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered**
8. But I can't get the any log in my app, and can't get the message notification.

I am use the development certificate and provision, so my test push site is set the gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195.

Have anyone known why I can't get the notification, but I can get the notification from the online test site?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I remember to have encountered same issue once, and I am not quite sure how I resolved it, as I chose to go with OneSignal later on as I didn't have a backend developer to write code for me. 
But could you once try replacing `ssl` in your line numbers 5,6 and 7 of the code with `tls` and try?